# HTML Canvas: images printed with createPattern are zoomed in

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I have a problem where any image I pass to createPattern are zoomed in by over 2x. I tried using:

```
contextInQuesiton.scale(1,1)
```

but the image still is initially zoomed in with my explicit instructions to do so.

Any ideas?

Code looks like this

```
app.canvas = document.getElementById('thecanvas');
app.context = app.canvas.getContext('2d');

var bgImg  = new Image();
bgImg.src  = 'bg.png';

bgImg.onload = function() {
    var bgDraw = app.context.createPattern(bgImg, 'repeat-y');
    app.context.rect(0, 0, 1000, 600);
    app.context.fillStyle = bgDraw;
    app.context.fill();
}
```

**Edit: Solution:**

Problem was that I wasn't setting width and height on the canvas element itself. I was setting it at first with javascript, and then with css. Both methods were causing that scaling issue. When i placed height and width back on the tag, everything went to normal. Weird.

Comment: Having code that reproduces the problem would really help. Could you make a [JSFiddle](http://JSFiddle.net)?

Comment: For future reference, CSS width and height are different from the canvas's width and height attributes. The html attributes set how many pixels there will be to draw (like the resolution) and the CSS sets the displayed size. Generally you don't need the CSS at all.

Answer (score 1):

`contextInQuestion.scale(1, 1)` doesn't do anything. It maps all points on the canvas to their current locations, which doesn't have any visible effect.

If everything on the canvas is twice as big as you want it to be, and you want to scale it to half its current size, you would use: `contextInQuestion.scale(0.5, 0.5)`

Comment: When I went to make an example I realized what was wrong. I was resizing the canvas in javascript to my config's width & height. However, I was doing this before anything else which is why I didn't think of it. Perhaps the async nature of js was printing the pattern before the resize occured. Thanks for taking time out to help!

Comment: .. actually, problem is still occuring! Though scaling down to 0.3, 0.3 makes it look normal. Either way, I don't think this is normal behavior.

Comment: @JeffK Are you using CSS to resize your canvas?